# Как открыть калькулятор в C?

Tags: windows, c

Пробую вот так

```
system("start %windir%\system32\calc.exe");
```

выдает ошибку и не открывает, что сделать?

Comment: @extazys, а warnings (или у Вас их нет?) про \\s и \\c Вас не смутили?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Для начала вспомнить про экранирование символов. Это когда \ нужно записывать как \\

Comment: в большинстве случаев распознает / вместо \ т.е.system("start %windir%/system32/calc.exe"); хоть это и юникс символ разделение пути но большинство функций в С корректно работают с ним и на вин платформах.

Answer (score 1):

В большинстве случаев распознает / вместо \ т.е.

```
system("start %windir%/system32/calc.exe");
```

хоть это и юникс символ разделение пути но большинство функций в С корректно работают с ним и на вин платформах.